# How can I extract stills from a movie?

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I would like to make a flipbook from a movie I made on my Mac. Is there any software that will extract, say 100 representative frames from 2 minutes of motion, or do I need to make screenshots manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ffmpeg should do the trick with something like

```
  ffmpeg -i video.avi -an -ss 00:00:00 -r 10 -vframes 50 image%d.jpg
```

should take one still every 10 seconds and a total of 50 frames (r is the interval) and vframes is the number

I'd suggest the [ffmpeg documentation for further finetuning](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC19)

You need to install ffmpeg so [here's the install guide for installing ffmpeg from source](http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html), though you can install [ffmpegx](http://www.ffmpegx.com/) and [grab the ffmpeg binary from there instead](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20061220082125312), or get it from [fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/ffmpeg) or [macports](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=ffmpeg)

Comment: Brilliant solution -- thank you so much!  The only think I did differently was to output the frames as .png's for better quality.

Comment: Just out of curiocity (i've never actually used a mac) - which install method did you go with?

Comment: I installed ffmpegx then grabbed the ffmpeg binary -- super simple.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using MPlayer for capturing still frames:

```
mplayer -nosound -sstep 1 -ss 00:02:00 -endpos 00:04:00 -vo png video.mkv
# mplayer -nosound -sstep 15 -vo png video.mkv
# -sstep = second steps, -ss = seek seconds, -vo = video output
```

And ImageMagick for combining the images:

```
montage *.png -tile 10x10 -geometry 150x+0+0 screencaps.jpg
```